# Convergence of a recursively defined sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, fixed-point-theorems

Let a sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be defined recursively $a_{n+1} = (1-a_n)^{\frac1p}$, where $p>1$, $0<a_0<(1-a_0)^{\frac1p}$. Let $a$ be the unique real root of $a=(1-a)^{\frac1p}$, $0<a<1$. It is clear $0<a_0<(1-a_0)^{\frac1p}\Leftrightarrow 0<a_0<a$. Prove

1) $a_{2k-2}<a_{2k}<a<a_{2k+1}<a_{2k-1}$ and $a_{2k+1}-a<a-a_{2k}$.

2) $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$.

---

Define $f(x):=(1-x)^{\frac1p}$. Consider $f^2$. When $p=2$, $a_{n+2}=f^2(a_n)=\big(1-(1-a_n)^{\frac12}\big)^{\frac12}$. $a_{n+2}>a_n\Leftrightarrow (1-a_n)(1+a_n)^2>1\Leftrightarrow a_n<(1-a_n)^{\frac12}$, and the conclusion is proved. But I am having difficulty generalizing this method to arbitrary $p>1$.

I also suspect that there is a general method to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: just be a little more careful with the tags..it is not a dynamical systems question i believe.

Comment: @MariosGretsas: I think it can be considered that, as it can be considered as the fixed point solution of $x=(1-x)^{\frac1p}$. What would you suggest as a better tag?

Comment: Personally for me just ''real analysis'' or calculus if fine

Comment: you need to prove $(1-(1-a_0)^{\frac 1p})^{\frac 1p} \geq a_0$ which does not look like a cakewalk.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: That is exactly what I have said in my note below the question.

Comment: When $p=2$, I am confused as to how $a_{n+2}=1-(1-a_n)^{1/2}$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Oops, that was wrong. Thanks for pointing out the error. I have now corrected it.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: Yet if you plot the graph of $y=f(x):=(1-x)^{\frac1p}$ and $y=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$, the trajectory of the recursive map spirals in to the fixed point so simply. It does not depend on the specific form of $f(x)$ so long it is asymmetric with respect to the line $y=x$ and concave. There must be a simple proof relying on only those qualitative properties.

Comment: @Hans I tried a concave approach already, but as one can see, $f(x)$ does not have an inflection point at $a=\lim a_n$, at least not generally.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I do not understand why you need an inflection point.

Comment: If the inflection point is off, then an argument of secants to prove the given bounds are only possible for one case, either for the odds or for the evens.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I meant to say there was no inflection point for a concave function by definition.

Comment: I was looking at $f(x)=(1-(1-x)^{1/p})^{1/p}$, my bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65447/discussion-between-hans-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: Huh, interestingly, let $x_0=f(x_0)=(1-x_0)^{1/p}$. I am having difficulty showing that $|f'(x_0)|\le1$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I have proved it. Actually the inequality is more strict, namely $0<-f'(x_0)<1$. It is not exactly trivial. I will add that to my answer, since it is needed to prove the second part of point 1) in the question.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: Just came back upon this problem. I would like to bring your attention to my answer below, if you have not yet seen it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We adopt the approach described in the note below the original question, i.e., by examining the composite $f^2$ of the original mapping $f$. We prove a more general statement than the original question. To this end, we prepare the following lemmas.

> Lemma 1: Suppose $g(x)$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ strictly increases with $x$ and $g(0)>0$. $a:=\inf\{x|g(x)< x\}>g(0)$ and $g(a)=a$ thus $a=\inf\{x|g(x)\le x\}$.

Proof: By contradiction. QED

> Lemma 2: Assume the same condition as in Lemma 1. $g^n(0)$ increases with $n$ and $g^n(0)<a$ $\forall n\in \mathbf N$ and thus  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g^n(0)$ exists and is bounded from above by $a$.

Proof: Choose an arbitrary $x_1\in[0,a)$. By the definition of $a$, $g(x_1)>x_1$. Since $g(x)$ increases with $x$, $g(x_1)<g(x)<g^2(x_1),\ \forall x\in(x_1,g(x_1))$. So $x<g(x_1)<g(x),\ \forall x\in(x_1,g(x_1)]$ (Note the statement is true for $x=g(x_1)$). By the definition of $a$ again, $g(x_1)<a$. Then $[x_1,g(x_1)]\subset(0,a)$. In conclusion, we have shown $x_1\in (0,a)\implies x_1<g(x_1)<a$, or $g^n(x_1)$ increases but is bounded from above by $a$. $g^n(x_1)$ has a limit and is bounded from above by $a$.

QED

> Lemma 3: Assume the same condition as in Lemma 1. In addition, $g$ is continuous. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g^n(0)=a$.

Proof: Suppose the limit is $a'<a$. By the definition of $a$, $a'<g(a')$. But $g$ is continuous, $a'=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(g^n(x_1))=g(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g^n(x_1))=g(a')>a',$ a contradiction.

QED

$f^2(x)$ increases with $x$ for monotonic $f$. Set $g=f^2$. Adding $g(x_1)>x_1$ for some $x_1$ would allow the application of Lemmas 1 and 2. Assuming continuity of $f$, and say $f(0)\ge 0$ and $\frac d{dx}g(0)=f'(f(0))f'(0)>1$, would guarantee just the aforementioned condition, as well as the application of Lemma 3.

The particular form of $f(x)=(1-x)^{\frac1p},\ \forall x\in[0,1],\ p>1$ in the original question is one such example. For this particular example, we show further that this $a$ is exactly the unique solution of $x=f(x)$. $g(x)=(1-(1-x)^{\frac1p})^{\frac1p}$. We now show there is a unique root for $g(x)-x=0,\ x\in(0,1)$ and that root is the unique root of $f(x)=x$. 
$$g''(x)= -\frac{p^2-1}{p^4} \big(1-(1-x)^{\frac1p}\big)^{\frac1p-2}(1- x)^{\frac1p-2}\Big((1-x)^{\frac1p}-\frac p{p + 1}\Big).$$
$(g(x)-x)''$ is strictly increasing with a unique root $x_0=1-\Big(1-\frac 1{p + 1}\Big)^p\in(0,1)$. This implies $g(x)<0\Longleftrightarrow x\in(0,a)$ and $g(x)>0\Longleftrightarrow x\in(a,1)$. With $g(0)=g(1)-1=0$, $g(x)-x=0$ therefore has only $1$ root in the open interval $(0,1)$.

---

$f(x):=(1-x)^{\frac1p},\ \forall x\in[0,1],\ p>1$. To prove point 1) $a-a_0>a_1-a$, we show $0<-f'(x)<1,\ x[0,x_0]$ where $x_0=f(x_0)$.

Because $-f'(x) = \frac1p(1-x)^{\frac1p-1}$ increases from $-f'(0)=\frac1p<1$ to $-f'(1)=\infty$ as $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$, $-f'(x_2)=1\text{ for some }x_2\in(0,1)\Longrightarrow -f'(x)<1\ \forall x[0,x_2)$. To show $-f'(x_0)<1$ it is sufficient to show $x_0<x_2$. To show the latter, it is sufficient to show $f(x_2)<x_2$.

Solving $-f'(x)=1$ we obtain $x_2=1-p^{-\frac p{p-1}}$. We want to show 
$$p^{-\frac1{p-1}}=f(x_2)<x_2=1-p^{-\frac p{p-1}} \tag1$$ 
or $\displaystyle\frac{\ln(p+1)}p<\frac{\ln p}{p-1}$. It is sufficient to show $h(p)=\frac{\ln(p)}{p-1}$ is a decreasing function in $p\in(1,\infty)$. Since
$$h'(p) = \frac1{(p-1)^2}\Big(1-\frac1p-\ln p\Big)=\frac1{(p-1)^2}\int_1^p \Big(\frac 1 {u^2}-\frac1u\Big)\,du<0,$$
we are done.

Alternatively, we prove inequality (1) as follows. Inequality (1) is equivalent to 
$$p^{\frac p{p-1}}=\big(1+(p-1)\big)^{\frac p{p-1}}>(p-1)\frac p{p-1}=p+1.$$ 
But the inequality in the middle is a special case of the [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Comment: How does one conclude that $x_1<g(x_1)\forall x_1\in(0,a)$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Are you referring to the second sentence of the second paragraph? If so, see the first half clause of the second sentence, i.e., "by the definition of $a$".

Comment: Oh... interesting approach.

Comment: Actually, your second paragraph has an error. "Since $g$ increases, $g(x_1)<g(x)<g^2(x_1),~\forall x\in(x_1,g(x_1))$". You implicitly assume that $x_1<g(x_1)$ before proving it, since$$g(x_1)<g(x)<g^2(x_1)$$requires$$g(x_1)<g^2(x_1)$$to be true.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: We had gone through why $x_1<g(x_1)$ in the subsequent discussion following your very first comment. Do you agree? If so, since $g$ increases, we have $g(u)<g(v),\ \forall u<v$. Let $u=x_1$ and $v=g(x_1)$. You have the desired result.

Comment: It is still flawed. Take $g(x)=x^2$. This is increasing, hence $g(u)<g(v),~\forall u<v$. Let $u=x_1$ and $v=g(x_1)$, where $x_1\in(0,1)$. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: In your example, $x_1<g(x_1)$ does not hold. However, that inequality is part of the premise for the conclusion. So you have to guarantee it holds to draw any meaningful conclusion. As for the validity of that premise, could you please review my second comment and the answer carefully? Could you please answer my question "Do you agree" in my last comment first before you go on to the other parts?

Comment: No I do not agree, as you haven't shown that $x_1<g(x_1)$ yet, as all your claims appear to be circular.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Do you agree that $a$ being the minimum of the set of numbers $x$ for which $x\ge g(x)$, the opposite of $x<g(x)$, is greater than $0$? If so, do you agree that any $0<x<a$ would lead to $x<g(x)$?

Comment: How do you propose to prove $a$ exists, without assuming it does?

Comment: That was why I asked you to read my answer carefully. :-) Have you read the second paragraph preceding the definition of $a$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65499/discussion-between-hans-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: No, I do not see how your second paragraph binds together. Take $f(x)=\sqrt x+2x,~g(x)=f^2(x)$, for example. This satisfies everything your $g$ does as far as what you've used,

Comment: See the [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65499/discussion-between-hans-and-simply-beautiful-art) to see that the given claim is probably true

Comment: For posterity, @SimplyBeautifulArt and I agree, after the discussion in the chat room, that his above example does not constitute a counterexample to my proof, since it satisfies all the premises and conclusions therein, once we realize $a=\infty$ in that example. By convention $\inf(S)=\inf(S\cup \{\infty\})$ for a set of real numbers $S$.

Comment: (Though I still prefer simply mentioning $g(1)=1$)