# Convergence acceleration of a recursively defined sequence $a_{n+1} = (1-a_n)^{\frac1p},\ p>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, computational-mathematics, convergence-acceleration

On [this question of recursive sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424908/64809), I have [proved its convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2425780/64809). As the sequence oscillates around its limit, the convergence rate can be accelerated. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Definition) is the definition of sequence (series) convergence acceleration. How would one accelerate the convergence rate of this sequence? Please provide proof and references.

Comment: What do you mean accelerate its convergence? For a series, that means find a faster method of computing the sum. Do you mean here to find the limit of the sequence? If so, the limit is the root of $x^p+x-1$. This can be found numerically to great precision using tools like [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). If not, what is meant?

Comment: @robjohn I would assume [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Definition) would define whether or not convergence is accelerated.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I would assume so, too. However, acceleration is usually applied to series, so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: The reference to the previous question seems like decent context to me. I am puzzled by the closure.

Comment: @The moderators: Was that the lack of the definition of sequence (series) convergence acceleration the concern for putting this question on hold? I have now added the reference for the definition. Please respond.

Comment: Oh dear, I knew i should've saved my half finished answer x.x

Answer (score 2):

The limit of the sequence
$$
a_{n+1}=(1-a_n)^{\frac1p}\tag1
$$
if it exists, would be the solution to 
$$
x^p+x-1=0\tag2
$$
Since
$$
\overbrace{1-p^{-\frac{p}{p-1}}}^{x}\gt\overbrace{\ \ p^{-\frac1{p-1}}\ \ }^{(1-x)^{\frac1p}}\tag3
$$
The root of $(2)$ must be less than $1-p^{-\frac{p}{p-1}}$.

For some $\xi$ between $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}-a_n
&=(1-a_n)^{\frac1p}-(1-a_{n-1})^{\frac1p}\\
&=\frac{(1-\xi)^{\frac1p-1}}p\,(a_{n-1}-a_n)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
If $\xi\lt1-p^{-\frac{p}{p-1}}$, $(4)$ represents a contraction map and will converge. This is precisely the condition satisfied by the root of $(2)$, as shown in $(3)$. Thus, in a neighborhood of the limit, the sequence $(1)$ converges geometrically with a ratio close to $\frac{(1-\xi_0)^{\frac1p-1}}p$ (the smaller the neighborhood, the closer the ratio), where $\xi_0$ is the root of $(2)$ in $(0,1)$.

**That is, in a neighborhood of the limit, the error in $\boldsymbol{(1)}$ decreases by a factor of $\boldsymbol{\frac{(1-\xi)^{\frac1p-1}}p}$ with each iteration.**

---

[Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) gives the solution to $(2)$ as the limit of the sequence
$$
\begin{align}
b_{n+1}
&=b_n-\frac{b_n^p+b_n-1}{pb_n^{p-1}+1}\\
&=\frac{(p-1)b_n^p+1}{pb_n^{p-1}+1}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
It can be shown that [Newton's Method converges quadratically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton.27s_iterative_method).

**That is, in a neighborhood of the limit, the error in $\boldsymbol{(5)}$ is squared with each iteration.**

---

**Example: $\boldsymbol{p=2}$**

Iterating $(1)$ with $a_0=0.5$ yields
$$
\begin{array}{l}
0.5\\
0.70710678118654752440\\
0.54119610014619698440\\
0.67735064763666020695\\
0.56802231678283538462\\
0.65725009183503703439\\
0.58544846755710529028\\
0.64385676391794992909\\
0.59677737564526528464\\
0.63499812941042174015\\
0.60415384678869525497\\
0.62916305772931769061\\
0.60896382673413558793\\
\end{array}
$$
This is converging, but quite slowly (about $1$ digit every $4.5$ iterations).

Iterating $(5)$ with $b_0=0.5$ yields
$$
\begin{array}{l}
0.5\\
0.625\\
0.61805555555555555556\\
0.61803398895790200138\\
0.61803398874989484822\\
0.61803398874989484820\\
0.61803398874989484820
\end{array}
$$
After $5$ iterations, we have $20$ digits of convergence (doubling the number of digits every iteration).

---

**Proof of $\boldsymbol{(3)}$**

Since $p\gt1$, Bernoulli's Inequality says that
$$
(1+(p-1))^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\gt1+p\tag6
$$
Multiplying both sides by $p^{-\frac{p}{p-1}}$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
1
&\gt(p+1)\,p^{-\frac{p}{p-1}}\\
&=p^{-\frac1{p-1}}+p^{-\frac{p}{p-1}}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
which is equivalent to $(3)$.

Comment: I like your proof via Bernoulli's inequality of inequality (3). That is different from mine linked to in my question. There are a couple of erroneous points though. Let $x_2=1-p^{-\frac p{p-1}}$. 1) The argument surrounding (4) is valid only for $f^{-1}(x_2)\le a_0\le x_2$. Even there, it needs to be shown the sequence remains in the interval.  2) You say "For $(4)$ to converge, we need $\xi\lt x_2$" indicating $\xi\lt x_2$ is a necessary condition. That is wrong. I think you intend to say: For $(4)$ to converge, it suffices for $\xi\lt x_2$.

Comment: In fact, there is no $0<\lambda<1 \ni \big(|f(a_0)-a_0|<\lambda|f^2(a_0)-f(a_0)|,\ \forall a_0\in[0,1]\big)$.

Comment: @Hans: Although I am talking about contraction mappings, where we *need* a factor strictly less than $1$ to guarantee convergence, I have changed the *need* to *want*. In your second comment, you have the inequality backwards, but what I am talking about is the region near the limit point. Setting $a_0=0$ or $a_0=1$ simply oscillates the sequence between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Have you checked out my point 1) in my first comment?

Comment: As I said, I was only checking near the point of convergence. I was not trying to show that no matter where we start, we get convergence. Even right on the PoC, the ratio is about $0.8$. I mainly wanted to show that where things converge, they converge faster using the second sequence.

Comment: Just to make it clear. You are NOT PROVING the sequence converges, even for a restricted initial point $a_0$. Is that correct? Your statement "Thus, the sequence (1) converges geometrically with ratio..." indicates the sequence is PROVED ("thus") to be convergent (by contraction). It is confusing. Could you please edit it to clearly state what you just said in your last comment, to the effect of: if it converges, by the continuity of $f'$ and $f'(x_0)<1$, the sequence for sufficiently large indices converges geometrically with ratio ...?

Answer (score 0):

From the previous question, we know that

$$a_{2n}<a<a_{2n+1}$$

And so, for any $m>0$, the weighted average of consecutive terms is closer to $a$.

$$a_{2n}<\frac{a_{2n}+ma_{2n+1}}{1+m}<a_{2n+1}$$

So $\frac{a_{2n}+ma_{2n+1}}{1+m}$ is closer to $a$ than $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$, yielding faster convergence. Specifically,

\begin{align}\small\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a-\frac{a_n+ma_{n+1}}{1+m}}{a-a_n}&=\frac1{1+m}+\frac m{1+m}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a-(1-a_n)^{1/p}}{a-a_n}\\&=\frac1{1+m}-\frac{ma}{p(1+m)(1-a)}\end{align}

For convergence to be fastest, we're interested in

$$0=\frac1{1+m}-\frac{ma}{p(1+m)(1-a)}$$

Which has the solution

$$m=\frac{p(1-a)}a$$

However, in order for this to be useful, you'll need to know what $a$ is. Replacing it with $a_n$ is good enough,

$$a=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n^2+p(1-a_n)^{(p+1)/p}}{a+p(1-a)}$$

which converges quadratically. (as fast as Newton's method)

The technique of weighting terms such that the resulting limit is zero can easily be extended to more generally things such as

$$f(x)=\frac{x+m_1(1-x)^{1/p}+m_2(1-(1-x)^{1/p})^{1/p}+\dots}{1+m_1+m_2+\dots}$$

where you'll want

$$f^{(k)}(a)=0$$

for as many $k$ as you are interested in. (It results in quadratic, cubic, quartic, etc. convergence depending on how many terms you use.)

Comment: Excuse my belated comment. Does this acceleration method have anything to do with the Aitken's delta squared process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitken%27s_delta-squared_process?

Comment: No I do not think so.